# Enviar variable js a otro archivo js

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero enviar la variable statuscondicions que tengo declarada dentro de un html en un  a un archivo js.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#condicions').click(function(){
    var statuscondicions = $(this).prop("checked");
  });
 });
```

Comment: y esa variable por lo que veo es un input checkbox, ¿correcto?

Comment: Entiendo quieres tomar el valor del checkbox, te deje un ejemplo para que me digas si entendí bien lo que buscas. https://jsfiddle.net/kce1optw/

Comment: Pero como la puedo enviar a otro archivo?

Comment: A otro archivo JS? debes explicarte un poco mejor para poder ayudarte